# Pie chart not using percent numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-pie

You see the following code, which draw you a pie chart

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \pie[rotate=20, color={white}, sum=auto, after number=, radius=2] {10/, 10/, 10/, 10/, 10/,10/, 10/, 10/}

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

`

I want the numbers 1 to 8 instead of 10. Is this with the command `\pie` possible?

Comment: Do you want the segments to be each 1/8 of total size and just number it from 1 to 8?

Comment: @moospit yes that's right. When I write the numbers 1 to 8 in the command line. LateX change the size of this pie, The 8 sectors of the circle should be the same size, only the description should be different (from 1 to 8 instead of 10)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware if `pgf-pie` is supporting this. Otherwise you can use the following code to create your chart. It could also  be used in a `newcommand` or the `pic`-environment to make it reusable.

You can adjust the parameters `mysegments` (number of segements) and `myradius` (radius of segments) for customization.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}    
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\mysegments{8}
    \def\myradius{2}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\mysegments} {
        \draw (0,0) --++ (360/\mysegments*\x:\myradius) arc (360/\mysegments*\x:360/\mysegments*(\x+1):\myradius);
        \node at (360/\mysegments*\x-180/\mysegments:\myradius/2) {\x};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered image]

Or with 15 segments (`\def\mysemgments{15}`):
[image: rendered image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want the segments to be able to have different sizes, you can do it like this:

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\Pie}[4][white]%
%[fill color] parts/color, size, rotate
{   \xdef\PieSum{0}
    \foreach \Seg/\Col in {#2}
    {   \pgfmathparse{\PieSum+\Seg}
        \xdef\PieSum{\pgfmathresult}
    }
    \xdef\PieDone{0}
    \begin{scope}[rotate=#4]
        \foreach \Seg/\Col [count=\C] in {#2}
        {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\PieDeg}{\Seg/\PieSum*360}
            \fill[#1, \Col, draw=black] (0,0) -- ++ (\PieDone:#3) arc (\PieDone:\PieDone+\PieDeg:#3) -- cycle;
            \node at  (\PieDone+\PieDeg/2:#3*0.7) {\C};
            \pgfmathparse{\PieDone+\PieDeg}
            \xdef\PieDone{\pgfmathresult}
        }
    \end{scope}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \Pie[orange!50]{5/blue!50,7/,13/,19/green!50,11/}{5}{90}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question as asking how to create the desired image with the *pgf-pie package* (not how to do it somehow  with TikZ) and this is how it works:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\pie[rotate=20, color={white}, sum=auto, radius=2,
text=inside,  % <----
before number=\phantom,  % <----
after number=,] {1/1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5, 1/6, 1/7, 1/8}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```