# Big circle with its radii

Tags: tikz-pgf

I don't know how to draw the radii of circle. This is what I can draw

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{patterns} 
\newcommand{\greatcircle}[5][]{ \path[#1,pattern=north west lines,pattern color=#1!60,rotate=#5,dashed] 
           (#2) circle [x radius=#3, y radius=#4]; 
\begin{scope}[rotate=#5] 
\clip (#3,0) rectangle ([xshift=-0.1,yshift=-0.1]-#3,-#4); 
\draw[#1] (#2) circle [x radius=#3, y radius=#4]; 
\end{scope} 
} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw[](0,0) circle [radius=2cm];  
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

and this is what I want...

[image]

Comment: I am not really sure I understand the connection between your `\greatcircle` command and your question. But about drawing a radius: Do you know how to express a point in polar coordinates? It might be helpful.

Comment: Check if [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283757/34759) helps you. It 's very similar to what you want, you only need to adjust the label position.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen , no. unfortunately I don't know

Comment: @moospit I don't know what to do. could you help me moore?

Comment: The notation looks like `(30:2cm)` for the point at radius 2cm and angle 30°. (Hint: Just search for “polar coordinate” in the TikZ documentation.)

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=2cm];
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {18,36,...,360}
  \draw (0,0)--(\i:2cm) node[shift=(\i:1em)]{\small\j}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am still a Ti*k*Z beginner, so my attempts are rather clumsy (but working ;-))

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,calc} 
\newcommand{\greatcircle}[5][]{ \path[#1,pattern=north west lines,pattern color=#1!60,rotate=#5,dashed] 
  (#2) circle [x radius=#3, y radius=#4]; 
  \begin{scope}[rotate=#5] 
    \clip (#3,0) rectangle ([xshift=-0.1,yshift=-0.1]-#3,-#4); 
    \draw[#1] (#2) circle [x radius=#3, y radius=#4]; 
  \end{scope} 
} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw[](0,0) circle [radius=2cm];  
\node (center) at (0,0) {};
\foreach \x in {0,20,...,360} {
  \pgfmathcos{\x}
  \edef\costemp{\pgfmathresult}
  \pgfmathsin{\x}
  \edef\sintemp{\pgfmathresult}
  \draw (0,0) -- (2*\costemp,2*\sintemp);
}
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,17} {
  \edef\currentangle{\pgfmathresult}
  \pgfmathcos{\x*20}
  \edef\costemp{\pgfmathresult}
  \pgfmathsin{\x*20}
  \edef\sintemp{\pgfmathresult}
  \node (A\x) at (2.2*\costemp,2.2*\sintemp) {\x};
}


\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```